# Screensaver not kicking in

Tags: screensaver

I have a screensaver applied via Group policy.  On only one of the machines, it never goes to screensaver.  If I look in the display control panel, the timeout is grayed out and set to 8 minutes... so obviously this is not a problem with applying the group policy.\

What could be causing this then?  Might it have something to do with the wireless mouse?  If not, what else should I look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a delay feature that [will increase the timeout period](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/20/9876113.aspx), but if the screensaver is *never* kicking in, it probably isn't.

It could be a rogue driver/program.

[Raymond Chen again](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/20/9876113.aspx):

> First of all, there are ways for programs to block the screen saver entirely. Calling `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED)`, is how a program says, "Even though there is no mouse or keyboard input, the screen is indeed in use, so don't blank it or start the screen saver."

There are a bunch of [bug-related reasons](http://support.microsoft.com/search/default.aspx?query=screen+saver+not+starting) in the Microsoft Knowledge Base.

Comment: Found it in the microsoft knowledgebase.  Just in case somebody has this issue in the future the article is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911895 .  Basically the microsoft wireless mouse was constantly sending signal strength info back to the computer and the computer was considering this as user activity.  Installing Microsoft's Intellipoint software for the mouse resolved the issue.